# Python Requests - Download File From Get Form

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I am using the Python requests package to download a CSV file. I am successfully navigating a webpage via Python but am stuck on the final stage of downloading the file. I am redirected here and the html looks (something )like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action='/export_data_test/convertxl.aspx' method='get'>
        <input type='hidden' name='SID' value='me@domain.com'>
    </form>
    <script>window.onload = function() {document.forms[0].submit();}</script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I am use to submitting forms that use the POST method but I see that GET is being used. Additionally, this page is automatically submitting the form "onload" and so the the browser normally downloads it immediately. It isn't clear how to capture this using the Python requests package.

I've tried:

```
session.get(domain+"/export_data_test/convertxl.aspx", data=payload, allow_redirects=True, verify=certifi.where())
```

However, this returns a response that contains no content (I expect a CSV file). Again, the behavior through the browser is that a file is downloaded.

Comment: The only point of script is just to open webpage and download csv file?

Comment: Yes, there are other form inputs that I've omitted but that's all there is on the page that I've been redirected to.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use `selenium` to get required file instead of `requests`? It seems to be easier solution..

Comment: No, our group uses Anaconda and so all code must be written using the standard package and nothing outside of it.

Comment: What is the response when you execute the `get`?

Comment: The status_code from the response is 200 but the content is empty. I know that I'm authenticating correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others make the same mistake as I did, the `get` method takes in `params` as an argument and **not** `data` (which is used for the `post` method). So, the correct way of sending the payload is as shown:

```
session.get(domain+"/export_data_test/convertxl.aspx", 
            params=payload, 
            allow_redirects=True, 
            verify=certifi.where())
```